# Throwing MySQLSyntaxErrorException regarding syntax of SQL in Struts

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc, struts

I am making a project on Struts framework.

I am getting a exception from server while inserting data in a table using SQL and I am unable to find the solution.

**The error is as following:**

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: 
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual 
that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the 
right syntax to use near ',,,,,,,'yes','yes',,,,'admin')' at line 1
```

**My code which is generating the error is as following:**

```
    sql="Insert into field_visit_details (visit_date,block,village,flw_category,
   flw_name,flw_contact_no,aware_zinc,
aware_ors,past_zinc,past_ors,qty_avail_zinc_ten,qty_avail_zinc_twe,qty_avail_zinc_syr,
qty_avail_ors,qty_disp_zinc_ten,qty_disp_zinc_twe,qty_disp_zinc_syr,qty_disp_ors,
stockout_zinc,stockout_ors,diar_cases_seen,diar_cases_reff,diar_deaths_less_than_five,
added_by)
 values 
('"+field_visit_date+"','"+block_row_one+"','"+village_row_one+"','"+flw_category_row_one
+"','"+flw_name_row_one+"','"+flw_contact_no_row_one+"','"+aware_zinc_row_one+"','"+
aware_ors_row_one+"','"+past_zinc_row_one+"','"+past_ors_row_one+"','"+
qty_avail_zinc_ten_row_one+"','"+qty_avail_zinc_twe_row_one+"','"+
qty_avail_zinc_syr_row_one+"','"+qty_avail_ors_row_one+"','"+qty_disp_zinc_ten_row_one
+"','"+qty_disp_zinc_twe_row_one+"','"+qty_disp_zinc_syr_row_one+"','"+
qty_disp_ors_row_one+"','"+stockout_zinc_row_one+"','"+stockout_ors_row_one+
"','"+diar_cases_seen_row_one+"','"+diar_cases_reff_row_one+"','"+diar_deaths_row_one
+"','"+loginid+"')";
            System.out.println(sql);
            int x=stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
            if(x>0)
                SUCCESS="admin";
```

**Table Structure is as following:**

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `field_visit_details` ( 
`field_visit_id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,   
`visit_date` date NOT NULL,   
`block` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   
`village` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   
`flw_category` varchar(45) NOT NULL,   
`flw_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   
`flw_contact_no` varchar(13) NOT NULL,   
`aware_zinc` varchar(10) NOT NULL,   
`aware_ors` varchar(10) NOT NULL,   
`past_zinc` varchar(10) NOT NULL,   
`past_ors` varchar(10) NOT NULL,   
`qty_avail_zinc_ten` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`qty_avail_zinc_twe` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`qty_avail_zinc_syr` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`qty_avail_ors` int(11) NOT NULL,  
`qty_disp_zinc_ten` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`qty_disp_zinc_twe` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`qty_disp_zinc_syr` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`qty_disp_ors` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`stockout_zinc` varchar(11) NOT NULL,   
`stockout_ors` varchar(11) NOT NULL,   
`diar_cases_seen` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`diar_cases_reff` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`diar_deaths_less_than_five` int(11) NOT NULL,   
`added_by` varchar(100) NOT NULL,   
PRIMARY KEY  (`field_visit_id`)   ) 
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

**The query when I printed in the console was :**

```
     Insert into field_visit_details (visit_date,block,village,flw_category,flw_name,
flw_contact_no,aware_zinc,aware_ors,past_zinc,past_ors,qty_avail_zinc_ten,
qty_avail_zinc_twe,qty_avail_zinc_syr,qty_avail_ors,
    qty_disp_zinc_ten,qty_disp_zinc_twe,qty_disp_zinc_syr,qty_disp_ors,stockout_zinc,
    stockout_ors,diar_cases_seen,diar_cases_reff,diar_deaths_less_than_five,added_by)
     values
     ('2014-07-02','ASDASD','','asha','asd+','99','yes','yes','yes','yes',
    '12','12','12','12','12','12','12','12','yes','yes','12','12','12','admin')
```

But the thing is that the query is inserting the data successfully in the table but still server is showing the above error.

I even used the above printed query directly in phpmyadmin and worked well without any problem.

Comment: I'd guess that somewhere in there one of those variables has a `'` character in it. Are you escaping your inputs properly?

Comment: You have a lot of empty variables that causes the `,,,,` and your variable `loginid` is null but the `added_by` column can't be null.

Comment: @MikeW Looking at the query I printed I guess there is no variable with `'` in its value.

Comment: @Tom Yes even i thought that but when i printed the query it shows a different picture.
No variable is empty..

Comment: First you shold give formatted code here as given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24978541/mysql-update-on-duplicate-key-only-inserting.

Comment: @xrcwrn formatting done
sry for the inconvinience

Comment: I guess you have a separate SQL tool an your server right? Then try your query there. Does it throw the same exception? If yes, then try to remove all `'` from any column that expects an integer.

Comment: @Tom Yes you are right I am having a different tool, and as you asked to do, I tried on it and no exception was thrown by that tool, the query worked well, the data was inserted.

Comment: The original query or the changed query?

Comment: @Tom the original one

Comment: Mhh thats odd. But may try removing every `'` for integer columns anyway. Couldn't hurt :D. If your program still doesn't work after what .. well then I'm out of clues.

Comment: One of the problem to use row JDBC against ORM framework you have to map your object's types to database types manually.

Comment: @RomanC Sry bt I am not getting whatever you are suggesting!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax exception in the SQL statement. The error message you have posted point to it.

So, you need to change SQL statement and fix syntax errors. For this purpose you should rewrite it to use `PraparedStatement` like in the example [JDBC PreparedStatement example – Insert a record](http://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-preparestatement-example-insert-a-record/).

And use appropriate to the database column types `set` methods when setting parameters to the prepared statement.

Comment: thanks for the try......but i found the error....actually i had on more insert query following the above code and that was creating problem.....

Comment: did you fix your errors? follow the link and learn how to write a query.