# DAO method error: Parameter index out of range

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I'm trying to call a DAO method in my Java EE project to add data to a table in MySQL.

**Here is the how the code looks:**

```java
 @Override
String execute(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws LoginSampleException {

    int height = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("height"));
    int length = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("length"));
    int width = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("width"));

    LegoHouseAlgorithm lego = new LegoHouseAlgorithm();

    ArrayList<Integer> bricks = lego.calc(height, length, width);

    request.setAttribute("longbrick", Integer.toString(bricks.get(0)));
    request.setAttribute("mediumbrick", Integer.toString(bricks.get(1)));
    request.setAttribute("shortbrick", Integer.toString(bricks.get(2)));
    request.setAttribute("wall3", Integer.toString(bricks.get(3)));
    request.setAttribute("wall4", Integer.toString(bricks.get(4)));
    request.setAttribute("wall5", Integer.toString(bricks.get(5)));

    int finalLongBrick = (bricks.get(0) + bricks.get(3)) * 2;
    int finalMediumBrick = (bricks.get(1) + bricks.get(4)) * 2;
    int finalShortBrick = (bricks.get(2) + bricks.get(5)) * 2;

    request.setAttribute("finallongbrick", finalLongBrick);
    request.setAttribute("finalmediumbrick", finalMediumBrick);
    request.setAttribute("finalshortbrick", finalShortBrick);
    
    
    try {
        LogicFacade.makeOrder(height, length, width);
    } catch (SQLException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Order.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    
    
return "order";
```

**`LogicFacade` class:**

```java
   public static OrderSample makeOrder(int height, int length, int width) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, LoginSampleException{
    OrderSample order = new OrderSample(height, width, length);
    UserMapper.createOrder(order);
    return order;
  }


public static void createOrder (OrderSample order) throws SQLException,    ClassNotFoundException, LoginSampleException{
    try{
        Connection con = Connector.connection();
        String SQL = "INSERT INTO orders (height, length, width) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(SQL);
        ps.setInt(order.getHeigh(), 1);
        ps.setInt(order.getLength(), 2);
        ps.setInt(order.getWidth(), 3);
        ps.executeUpdate();
        ResultSet rs = ps.getGeneratedKeys();
        rs.next();
        int id = rs.getInt(1);
        order.setId(id);
        
     } catch ( ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex ) {
        throw new LoginSampleException(ex.getMessage());
    }    
}
```

whatever parameters I type in my HTML form I get the error:

```java
Parameter index out of range ((inserted number) > number of parameters, which is 3).
```

Comment: You haven't shown a Minimal Complete Verifiable Example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  Try debugging your code, see where the exception occurs, the `bricks` probably isn't getting generated the way you think it is.

Comment: Okay thank you, i will try that, everything worked fine, untill i added my JDBC method, the values get displayed the right way etc.

Comment: I think you have switched the order of parameters in your prepared statement.  Try `ps.setInt(1, order.getHeigh());`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have entered parameters to [`setInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt(int,%20int)) incorrectly. First parameter is the index and second is the value.

To correct it use this code:

```
ps.setInt(1,order.getHeigh());
ps.setInt(2,order.getLength());
ps.setInt(3,order.getWidth());
```

In the [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24982369/573032) you can learn how to use `PreparedStatement`.

Answer (score 0):

From the looks of the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt(int,%20int)) you have to switch the order of your parameters passed to `setInt()` in your `createOrder` method.
First parameter should be the index, second the value